# Stop the editor from carriage returning whilst editing css in Codeanywhere

Tags: html, css, codeanywhere

I have a quite unique way of typin css. It is in a way that makes me understand my code a whole lot better, than just randomly putting things everywhere. This allows me to use one file with no problem, rather than putting my project into a whole lot of different css files, that would end  up in me having to compile them afterwards.

Let us consider:

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I then most of the time, want to create another styling of a different element, tabbed in one from the previous one.

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
    header
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 233px;
    }
```

But upon doing so, the cursor jumps back to the very start of the line, simply by hitting enter after body, as well as upon creating the brackets after the `header`, in this case. This is very time consuming, as I have to indent manually after creating the brackets, as well as the `header`.

Especially for the brackets, which automatically after being created ends up like the following:

```
    header
{

}
```

It there a setting to disable, or change, this default behavior?

Comment: Probably not possible, but in what editor?

Comment: The editor is Codeanywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer would be get rid of your unique way of typin css and use css style guides, for example: https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.xml

A diffrent answer to your question would be to use Sublime Text, as far is i can see it does what you want. So the 'problem' is probarly with your editor.

Comment: Getting rid of my unique way was not part of my question. Sublime text is not as portable of a solution.